# Singly linked list implementation

Tags: c++, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel

I feel like there is room for improvement in the push/pop methods. Any suggestions?

```
#include <exception>

template <typename T>
class List
{
public:

                    List();
                    ~List();
    void            PushBack(const T &data);
    void            PushFront(const T &data);
    void            PopBack();
    void            PopFront();
    void            Clear();    
    bool            IsEmpty() const;
    unsigned int    Size() const;
    T&              Front() const;
    T&              Back() const;

private:

    template <typename T>
    struct Node
    {
        Node(const T &data) : data(data), next(NULL) {}
        T      data;
        Node  *next;
    };

    Node<T> *head;
    Node<T> *tail;
};

template <typename T>
List<T>::List()
    : head(NULL),
      tail(NULL)
{

}

template <typename T>
List<T>::~List()
{
    Clear();
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::PushBack(const T &data)
{   
    if ( !head )
    {
        head = new Node<T>(data);
        tail = head;
        return;
    }

    tail->next = new Node<T>(data);
    tail = tail->next;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::PushFront(const T &data)
{
    Node<T> *tmp = head;
    head = new Node<T>(data);
    head->next = tmp;

    if ( !tail )
    {
        tail = head;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::PopBack()
{
    //empty list
    if ( !head )
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Can't pop from empty list");
    }

    //list with one element
    if ( head == tail )
    {
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        return;
    }

    Node<T> *current = head;
    while ( current->next != tail )
    {
        current = current->next;
    }

    delete tail;
    tail = current;
    tail->next = NULL;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::PopFront()
{
    //empty list
    if ( !head )
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Can't pop from empty list");
    }

    //list with one element
    if ( head == tail )
    {
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        return;
    }

    Node<T> *tmp = head->next;
    delete head;
    head = tmp;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::Clear()
{
    Node<T> *current = head;
    while ( head )
    {
        current = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete current;
    }

    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
}

template <typename T>
bool List<T>::IsEmpty() const
{
    return ( head == NULL );
}

template <typename T>
unsigned int List<T>::Size() const
{
    unsigned int size = 0;
    for ( Node<T> *current = head; current; current = current->next )
    {
        ++size;
    }

    return size;
}

template <typename T>
T& List<T>::Front() const
{
    if ( !head )
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Can't return value from empty list");
    }

    return head->data;
}

template <typename T>
T& List<T>::Back() const
{
    if ( !head )
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Can't return value from empty list");
    }

    return tail->data;
}
```

Comment: Hm, I realised there is no way of iterating through it. I should implement an iterator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Consider using a different naming convention for your data members and methods, such as camelCase or snake_case.  Your user-defined types are already uppercase, which is okay.  Whichever you choose, it's more readable to keep them separate.
- The push/pop methods here imply that this is a stack implementation, but a linked list should be capable of inserting or removing a node at *any* location in the list.  Consider adding additional functions for this.  For an idea of typical linked list functions, [read this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).
- Since you're using a list `class`, you should have a size member to maintain.  Your `Size()` method is calculating the size at each call by traversing, which is O(n).

  Instead, have a size data member and update it with other operations:

  - initialize to 0 in the initializer list
  - increment with each push
  - decrement with each pop
  - reset to 0 with each clear

  When you call `Size()`, it should just return the data member value, which is O(1).

  It should also return a `std::size_t`.  It is closest to the return type used in STL containers, and a very large list size may not fit inside an `unsigned int`.
- Instead of having a `return` in `PushFront()`, put the last two lines into an `else` block.
- Shouldn't `popBack()` check `tail` if `PopFront()` checks `head`?  Although they may be pointing to the same node if there's only one node, but the intent is more clear this way.
- You should probably also have a `Front()` and `Back()` that return a `T const&`, in case the reference will not be modified or a `const` value is needed.
- You should have some way of displaying the list.  For that, consider overloading `operator<<` for the `List` class (instead of a display function), allowing you to do this:

  ```
  List list;
  std::cout << list;
  ```

  You could also overload `Node`'s operator, allowing you to output a node within the `List` class.
- `std::out_of_range` is defined in `<stdexcept>`, not `<exception>`.

Comment: Thank You! I might edit with the implemented iterator later.

Comment: @Innkeeper: You're welcome!  As that change may affect more of your code, I'd recommend asking a new question with that implementation.  Follow-up questions are okay here.

Comment: What's the problem with the capitalization convention? I don't see any issue.

Comment: @200_success: More of a personal preference, I suppose.  It just seems odd sharing it with types, variables, and functions.

Comment: If I overloaded `operator<<`, I still wouldn't have any way to iterate through and say, modify each item. Wouldn't an iterator/const iterator be more useful? Well, these could coexist, but I'm on the right track thinking this really needs an iterator, right?

Comment: @Innkeeper: Yes, iterators would still be useful.  They could still be used for modifying nodes as well as displaying the list in a loop.  They can still coexist with `operator<<`.  The operator would display the entire list, whereas the iterators can display a portion of it (think of how `std::begin()` and `std::end()` are used in loops).

Answer (score 7):

IMO, if you're going to implement a linked list (probably shouldn't--they're pretty worthless) it's best to specify both the data *and* the `next` pointer when you create a node.

```
Node(const T &data, struct node *next = nullptr) : data(data), next(next) {}
```

This lets you simplify quite a bit of the insertion code. For example:

```
template <typename T>
void List<T>::PushFront(const T &data) {

    head = new node(data, head);

    if ( !tail )
        tail = head;
}
```

The other big thing that jumped out at me (that Jamal hasn't already discussed) was using `NULL`. I'd prefer `nullptr`, unless you're stuck with an ancient compiler that doesn't support it yet (in which case, you still want to do it, but after updating your compiler).

Comment: I haven't forgotten about `nullptr`, but I sometimes feel tempted to not bring it up if it appears that the OP isn't already using C++11.

Comment: Yeah, much clearer with that ctor, thanks!

Comment: Linked lists are not worthless, you need to know when to use the correct data structure. Linked lists have constant time insertion and deletion at the front and tail or anywhere where you already have a pointer. If you are frequently inserting or deleting at the front or tail (like a queue) then a linked list is just fine. A plain vector or array would perform terribly in this case making a `pop` operation an \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ operation.

Comment: @EmilyL.: You sound like you were in the data structures classes I taught 20+ years ago. At that time, the advice was even sort of close to accurate. Unfortunately, it wasn't nearly as good then as I thought, and it's much less so now.

Comment: @JerryCoffin "Right tool for the job" is no longer applicable? Then I'm out of a job :'( Jokes aside, I'm not saying to use linked lists for everything or even most things. I'm saying that there are use cases and you need to know what structure you need and how it will perform on your target machine. Blanket statements like "linked-lists are worthless" are not constructive or educational in any way.

Comment: @EmilyL.: Okay, if you find somebody making an unqualified statement that "linked-lists are worthless", feel free to tell them so. So far, you're showing much more about your inability to quote accurately than anything about linked lists though. If you really do have a good use-case for them, feel free to add it as an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2429217/179910).

Comment: That question already has plenty of good answers of uses for linked lists. But to take two examples not brought up there: free lists in memory pools, managing free heap blocks (operating systems topic). False blanket statement saying linked lists are worthless here: "(probably shouldn't--they're pretty worthless)", they have plenty of uses as seen by your link and my examples. Also I implore you to avoid using ad hominems.

Comment: @EmilyL.: I implore you to learn what *ad hominem* means before accusing people of using it (there has been nothing remotely similar to an *ad hominem* attack here). And free heap block/free lists in memory pools are really one topic, not two (and while linked lists aren't entirely worthless there, they're rarely ideal either).

Comment: @JerryCoffin This "So far, you're showing much more about your inability to quote accurately than anything about linked lists though." is an ad hominem attack, more specifically you're poisoning the well; My ability to quote has no bearing on my knowledge of linked lists. I have shown usages and plenty of arguments for linked lists having theirs uses counter to your blanket statement while you have failed to show any arguments for your statement. For example why is handling a heap like a linked list rarely ideal for example? What is a better way?

Comment: @EmilyL.: An *ad hominem* argument has the form: "X's argument should not be believed because X is an evil person." The wording can obviously change, but to be an *ad hominem* attack, it still has to have that intent: saying somebody's argument should not be believed because they're evil. No such statement (nor implication) has been made here.

Comment: @EmilyL.: As for why heaps as linked lists are rarely ideal: for pretty much the usual reasons, especially poor cache locality. The primary intent of a free list is to find a block for allocation. Given caching, a bitmap of free blocks  (for one possible alternative) can do that with substantially less cache pollution.